# jQuery IE issue when pasting a content with breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container and the goal is picking up the pasted content:

given the following is my content (that I am going to select and paste them into the container):

```
1234
5678
4321
```

and I use the following jquery code:

```
$('.parent').on("paste", ".container", function (event) {
  var element = this;
  var text = $(element).val();
  var txtList = text.split(" ");

});
```

On other browsers when I paste the content I get all three lines (stored in variable text) but on IE I only get the first line (1234) when I paste. I guess the issue is with the breaks.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What platform are you using. That combined with the fact that IE tends to do a bad job a picking character encoding for a page could have something to do with ti. I have had similar problem with cross platform applications written by Mac programmers. It also depends - are you trying to paste it into an input box or textarea?

Comment: using windows! when I change the content format to 1234 5678 4321, it works fine!

Comment: it is not the content format that is the problem. It is the character encoding/conversion that is or that fact that some browsers ignore everything after the carriage return when pasting in to a text input compared to a textarea.